# Execute query command (dynamic sql) runs faster than ordinary query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

Why is the second query with `EXECUTE` command runs ~4 times faster than first query without one? How can I solve this problem?

Why additional table (Workatable) created in the second case?

**Variables:**

```
DECLARE @count INT, @followerId BIGINT
SET @count=1024
SET @followerId=10
```

**First query (Usual query):**

```
SELECT TOP (@count) Photo.* FROM Photo
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT accountId FROM Follower
WHERE Follower.followerId=@followerId
AND Follower.accountId = Photo.accountId) 
AND Photo.closed='False'
ORDER BY Photo.createDate DESC
```

**Log:**

SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 7 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Table 'Photo'. Scan count 952, logical reads 542435, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Follower'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 1466 ms,  elapsed time = **9620 ms**.

**Execution plan:**

[image: First query execution plan]

**Second query (the same query with `EXECUTE`):**

```
EXEC ('SELECT TOP (' +@count + ') Photo.* FROM Photo
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT  accountId FROM Follower
WHERE Follower.followerId=' +@followerId + '
AND Follower.accountId = Photo.accountId) 
AND Photo.closed=''False''
ORDER BY Photo.createDate DESC')
```

**Log:**

SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time:  CPU time = 25 ms, elapsed time = 25 ms.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Photo'. Scan count 952, logical reads 542707, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Follower'. Scan count 6, logical reads 9, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 1374 ms,  elapsed time = 2140 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 1405 ms,  elapsed time = **2165 ms**.

Answer (score 4):

This could be because the second query (depending on the context of the first query) is more optimizable, since the variables become inline constants. Compare:

```
DECLARE @count INT, @followerId BIGINT
SET @count=1024
SET @followerId=10

SELECT TOP (@count) Photo.* FROM Photo
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT accountId FROM Follower
WHERE Follower.followerId=@followerId
AND Follower.accountId = Photo.accountId) 
AND Photo.closed='False'
ORDER BY Photo.createDate DESC
```

With:

```
SELECT TOP (1024) Photo.* FROM Photo
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT accountId FROM Follower
WHERE Follower.followerId=10
AND Follower.accountId = Photo.accountId) 
AND Photo.closed='False'
ORDER BY Photo.createDate DESC
```

This is especially true if your first query was part of a stored proc, the variables were arguments and that particular query was optimized with different parameter values when the stored proc was compiled.

Comment: You have various options to deal with this, e.g. OPTION RECOMPILE on the statement, OPTIMIZE FOR, setting the parameterization for the database to forced...